# Permission Overwrite not changing the discord channel permissions. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Alright, So I am creating a ticket system, and when the channel is created I save the user who created the channel in JSON and when the ticket is about to be closed, I read the member and try to change the channel permission so that they can't send message but read and they can react. But when I do this it doesn't work. Not error at all.

Exact Place of Code:

```
            if str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                ticket_creator_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_creator_ids.json", ctx.channel)
                ticket_creator_user_id = ticket_creator_dict.get(str(ticket_channel.id))
                ticket_creator_user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=ticket_creator_user_id)

                guilds_support_roles_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("support_roles_ids.json", ctx.channel)
                guild_support_role_id = guilds_support_roles_dict.get(str(ctx.guild.id))
                guild_support_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=guild_support_role_id)

                new_ticket_channel_overwrites = {
                    guild_support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                    ticket_creator_user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False, add_reactions=True),
                    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
                }

                await ticket_channel.edit(overwrites=new_ticket_channel_overwrites)
```

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import discord
import json
import datetime

class TicketSystem(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.create_ticket_msgs = []

    async def read_json_to_dict(self, json_file_name, channel):
        json_dict = {}

        try:
            with open(f"json/{json_file_name}", "r") as json_file:
                json_dict = json.load(json_file)
        except:
            embed_message = discord.Embed(title="Error: JSON", description="Please create a support ticket in the Nexus Developments Discord to get this resloved - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf",colour=discord.colour.Colour.red())
            embed_message.set_footer(text="Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

            await channel.send(embed=embed_message)

        return json_dict

    async def check_create_ticket_reaction(self, reaction, user):
        for create_ticket_msg in self.create_ticket_msgs:
            if create_ticket_msg.id == reaction.message.id:
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
                    if user != self.bot.user:
                        return True

    async def get_ticket_counter(self, message):
        ticket_counter_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_counter.json", message.channel)

        current_ticket_number = ticket_counter_dict.get(str(message.guild.id))

        if current_ticket_number is None:
            current_ticket_number = 0

        return current_ticket_number

    async def get_guild_ticket_catergory(self, message):
        ticket_categories_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_categories_ids.json", message.channel)

        guild_ticket_category_id = ticket_categories_dict.get(str(message.guild.id))

        guild_ticket_category = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, id=guild_ticket_category_id)

        if guild_ticket_category is None:
            embed_message = discord.Embed(title="Error: TicketCategoryNotFound", description="Please create a support ticket in the Nexus Developments Discord to get this resloved - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", colour=discord.colour.Colour.red())
            embed_message.set_footer(text="Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed_message)
        else:
            return guild_ticket_category

    async def get_guild_support_roles(self, message):
        support_roles_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("support_roles_ids.json", message.channel)

        guild_support_role_id = support_roles_dict.get(str(message.guild.id))

        guild_support_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=guild_support_role_id)

        if guild_support_role is None:
            embed_message = discord.Embed(title="Error: SupportRolesNotFound", description="Please create a support ticket in the Nexus Developments Discord to get this resloved - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", colour=discord.colour.Colour.red())
            embed_message.set_footer(text="Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed_message)
        else:
            return guild_support_role

    async def write_ticket_counter_to_json(self, message, current_ticket_number):
        ticket_counter_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_counter.json", message.channel)

        ticket_counter_dict[str(message.guild.id)] = current_ticket_number

        with open("json/ticket_counter.json", "w") as ticket_counter_json:
            json.dump(ticket_counter_dict, ticket_counter_json)

    async def create_ticket_transcript(self, ticket_channel: discord.TextChannel):
        ticket_channel_messages = await ticket_channel.history(oldest_first=True).flatten()

        transcript_path = f"transcripts/{datetime.date.today()}_{ticket_channel.name}_Transcript.txt"

        with open(transcript_path, "w+") as ticket_transcript:
            for ticket_channel_message in ticket_channel_messages:
                ticket_transcript.write(f"{ticket_channel_message.created_at} - {ticket_channel_message.author.name}#{ticket_channel_message.author.discriminator} - {ticket_channel_message.content}\n")

        return transcript_path

    async def write_ticket_id_to_user_id(self, ticket_channel, user):
        ticket_creator_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_creator_ids.json", ticket_channel)

        ticket_creator_dict[str(ticket_channel.id)] = user.id

        with open("json/ticket_creator_ids.json", "w") as ticket_creator_json:
            json.dump(ticket_creator_dict, ticket_creator_json)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        create_ticket_msg = reaction.message

        checked_create_ticket_reaction = await self.check_create_ticket_reaction(reaction, user)

        if checked_create_ticket_reaction:
            await create_ticket_msg.add_reaction("✅")
            await create_ticket_msg.add_reaction("❎")

            confirm_embed_message = discord.Embed(description="Please confirm your ticket creation with ✅ (for yes) and ❎ (for no)",color=discord.colour.Colour.green())
            confirm_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

            confirm_creation_msg = await create_ticket_msg.channel.send(embed=confirm_embed_message)

            def ticket_creation_check(ticket_creation_reaction, ticket_creation_user):
                return ticket_creation_user == user and str(ticket_creation_reaction.emoji) in {"✅", "❎"}

            try:
                ticket_creation_reaction, ticket_creation_user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=ticket_creation_check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                for reaction in ["", "✅", "❎"]:
                    await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                for reaction in ["✅", "❎"]:
                    await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, self.bot.user)

                await confirm_creation_msg.delete()
            else:
                await confirm_creation_msg.delete()

                if str(ticket_creation_reaction.emoji) == "❎":
                    for reaction in ["", "✅", "❎"]:
                        await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                    for reaction in ["✅", "❎"]:
                        await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, self.bot.user)

                if str(ticket_creation_reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                    for reaction in ["", "✅", "❎"]:
                        await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                    for reaction in ["✅", "❎"]:
                        await create_ticket_msg.remove_reaction(reaction, self.bot.user)

                    current_ticket_number = await self.get_ticket_counter(create_ticket_msg)
                    guild_ticket_category = await self.get_guild_ticket_catergory(create_ticket_msg)
                    guild_support_role = await self.get_guild_support_roles(create_ticket_msg)

                    ticket_channel_overwrites = {
                        guild_support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                        create_ticket_msg.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
                    }

                    current_ticket_number += 1

                    users_ticket_channel = await guild_ticket_category.create_text_channel(f"ticket-{current_ticket_number}", overwrites=ticket_channel_overwrites)

                    await self.write_ticket_counter_to_json(create_ticket_msg, current_ticket_number)

                    await self.write_ticket_id_to_user_id(users_ticket_channel, user)

                    ticket_embed_message = discord.Embed(description=f"Support will be with you shortly.\nTo close this ticket react with ", color=discord.colour.Colour.green())
                    ticket_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                    await users_ticket_channel.send(f"{user.mention} {guild_support_role.mention}")
                    await users_ticket_channel.send(embed=ticket_embed_message)

    @commands.command(name="ticketmsg")
    async def send_create_ticket_msg(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
        if channel is None:
            channel = ctx.message.channel

        embedMessage = discord.Embed(title="Create A Ticket", description="To create a ticket react with ", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.colour.Colour.green())
        embedMessage.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

        create_ticket_msg = await channel.send(embed=embedMessage)
        await create_ticket_msg.add_reaction("")

        await ctx.message.delete()

        self.create_ticket_msgs.append(create_ticket_msg)

    @commands.command(name="close")
    async def close_ticket(self, ctx, ticket_channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
        if ticket_channel is None:
            ticket_channel = ctx.message.channel

        confirm_closure_embed_message = discord.Embed(description=f"Please confirm the closure of {ticket_channel.mention}\n React with ✅ to close and ❎ to keep the ticket open", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, colour=discord.colour.Colour.red())
        confirm_closure_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

        confirm_closure_message = await ctx.send(embed=confirm_closure_embed_message)
        await confirm_closure_message.add_reaction("✅")
        await confirm_closure_message.add_reaction("❎")

        def ticket_creation_check(ticket_closure_reaction, ticket_closure_user):
            return ticket_closure_user == ctx.author and str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) in {"✅", "❎"}

        try:
            ticket_closure_reaction, ticket_closure_user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=ticket_creation_check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return
        else:
            if str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) == "❎":
                return

            if str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                ticket_creator_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("ticket_creator_ids.json", ctx.channel)
                ticket_creator_user_id = ticket_creator_dict.get(str(ticket_channel.id))
                ticket_creator_user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=ticket_creator_user_id)

                guilds_support_roles_dict = await self.read_json_to_dict("support_roles_ids.json", ctx.channel)
                guild_support_role_id = guilds_support_roles_dict.get(str(ctx.guild.id))
                guild_support_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=guild_support_role_id)

                new_ticket_channel_overwrites = {
                    guild_support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                    ticket_creator_user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=False, add_reactions=True),
                    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
                }

                await ticket_channel.edit(overwrites=new_ticket_channel_overwrites)

                transcript_status_embed_message = discord.Embed(description="Creating Transcript...", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), colour=discord.colour.Colour.orange())
                transcript_status_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                transcript_status_message = await ctx.send(embed=transcript_status_embed_message)

                transcript_path = await self.create_ticket_transcript(ticket_channel)

                transcript_dm_user = await self.bot.fetch_user(223200232232452096)

                transcript_status_embed_message = discord.Embed(description=f"Created Transcript. Sending transcript to {transcript_dm_user.name}#{transcript_dm_user.discriminator}", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), colour=discord.colour.Colour.green())
                transcript_status_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                await transcript_status_message.edit(embed=transcript_status_embed_message)

                if transcript_dm_user.dm_channel is None:
                    await transcript_dm_user.create_dm()

                transcript_file = discord.File(transcript_path)

                transcript_dm_embed_message = discord.Embed(title=f"Support Ticket Transcript: {ticket_channel.name}", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), colour=discord.colour.Colour.green())
                transcript_dm_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                await transcript_dm_user.dm_channel.send(embed=transcript_dm_embed_message, file=transcript_file)

                ticket_closure_embed_message = discord.Embed(description="Ticket has been closed", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), colour=discord.colour.Colour.green())
                ticket_closure_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                await ticket_channel.send(embed=ticket_closure_embed_message)

                ticket_closure_option_embed_message = discord.Embed(description="Reopen Ticket: \nDelete Ticket: ⛔", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), colour=discord.colour.Colour.red())
                ticket_closure_option_embed_message.set_footer(text=f"Created By Nexus Developments - https://discord.gg/YmdugDf", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/MRBsIpe.png")

                ticket_closure_options_message = await ticket_channel.send(embed=ticket_closure_option_embed_message)
                await ticket_closure_options_message.add_reaction("")
                await ticket_closure_options_message.add_reaction("⛔")

                def ticket_options_check(ticket_options_reaction, ticket_options_user):
                    return ticket_options_user != self.bot.user and str(ticket_options_reaction.emoji) in {"", "⛔"}

                try:
                    ticket_closure_reaction, ticket_closure_user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=86400.0,check=ticket_options_check)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    return
                else:
                    if str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) == "⛔":
                        await ticket_channel.delete()

                    if str(ticket_closure_reaction.emoji) == "":
                        return

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TicketSystem(bot))
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: The question doesn't include enough information to recreate the issue. Also, the code sample has extraneous information. As the OP is gone, if anyone has a similar question, someone would need to post a new question according to the [guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it might be answerable. However, first check that any such attempt isn't answered by "[How do you use permission overwrites? Discord.py Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61821522/90527)".

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what kind of issue is going on but it might be that it can't detect the reaction. So instead of using an actual emoji in the check_create_ticket_reaction function use the emoji id instead:

`reaction.emoji.id == <insert the id here>`

Comment: wait sorry the answer went wrong i meant reaction.emoji.id == <insert the id here>

Comment: you can edit your own answers, please do not correct your own answer in the comments.