# How do you use permission overwrites? Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to make a mute command and a ticket command for my discord bot but i can't wrap my head around permission overwrites. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a command for editing a certain member's permissions server-wide (i.e. for each text channel the bot can see):

## Example

```py
import discord # if you get an error about discord not being defined, include this at the top

@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        perms = channel.overwrites_for(member)
        perms.send_messages = False
        await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=perms, reason="Muted!")
    await ctx.send(f"{member} has been muted.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`TextChannel.overwrites_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites_for) - Keep in mind this can take in a Role or User/Member object.
- [`TextChannel.set_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)
- [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels)

Comment: But what if i want to use it for a role? Like a muted role

Comment: @enderelijas One way of doing it is to make sure that your muted role has `send_messages = False` for each text channel, and you can use [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) to give them the muted role, meaning they won't be able to talk in any of the channels you have `send_messages = False` in

Comment: how would i make it so that i dont have to say the channel name after doing the command? Like now i have to do ?mute @user #channel

Comment: Iterate through each text channel: [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels)

Comment: so instead of doing channel: discord.TextChannel i do channel: Guild.text_channels?

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: it says undefined variable Guild. How do i define it again?

Comment: @enderelijas Did you see the updated answer? I edited it :)

Comment: yeah i just forgot to delete one piece of code sorry

Comment: No problemo. Let me know if it works as you want it to!

Comment: yes it does i have closed the question until i need further assistance thank you!